# How does this user have so many upvotes but so little reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

So I randomly found [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009).

Said user has **648 reputation**.

Said user also has quite a few questions and answers, such that, even with the 200 reputation cap per post, should still have *way* more reputation than that (probably somewhere in the 1000s).

Said user also has almost no down-votes on his/her questions or answers and only 1 down-vote cast.

**Note:** I managed to figure it out just before posting, but I thought I'd share the knowledge in case anyone was wondering something similar.

**Upvoted questions and answers:**

[image: Q+A]

**Downvoted questions:**

[image: Q]

**Downvoted answers:**

[image: A]

**Votes cast:**

[image: Votes]

Comment: Of all the questions to self-answer, this seems like an odd choice

Comment: Just as a side note look at [this graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/27050/ant2009?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [the bounties tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009?tab=bounties&sort=offered) one can see that that user really loves awarding bounties.

[image: Bounties]

This would be the reason, as bounties come off of your own reputation.

As Andrew Barber pointed out, an alternative cause is having multiple posts community-deleted as spam. Those come with -100 reputation each. Though this seems unlikely given the lack of significant down-votes to the user's other posts.

Comment: `18 Offered bounties for 7,050 reputation` [it says](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70942/ant2009?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' Thanks for that, edited.

Comment: another, more generalized possible answer for people showing less reputation than might seem proper could be having multiple posts community-deleted as spam. Those come with -100 each.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Edited.